# Spring JDBCTemplate: How to call a View in MySQL schema from Spring Controller

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I have a View in MySQL schema that already do the following:
My question is how do I call that View using jdbctemplate instead?

```
    // insert person into database
    jdbcTemplate.update(
        "INSERT INTO Person (FirstName, LastName, Address, Phone, City, State, ZipCode) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName(), person.getAddress(), person.getPhone(), person.getCity(), person.getState(), person.getZipCode()
    );

    // get this persons generated id from the DB
    int personId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "SELECT Id FROM Person WHERE FirstName=? AND LastName=?", new Object[]{person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName()}, int.class);

    // create user account for person
    jdbcTemplate.update(
        "INSERT INTO User (person_Id, active, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
        personId, 1, username, password
    );

    int userId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "SELECT user_id FROM User WHERE username=? AND password=?", new Object[]{username, password}, int.class);

    // finally add role to user
    // by default, all users are set to Customer roles.
    jdbcTemplate.update(
        "INSERT INTO User_role (user_id, role_id) VALUES (?, ?)",
        userId, Role.CUSTOMER_ROLE
    );
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried and explain the specific problem with it. On SO you're expected to give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: There is no code to try since my question is essentially "How do I even try?". I provided more details to make my point more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Views` can be accessed just like any other tables in JDBC while selecting the data. So, something like the following works fine for us.

```
 int personId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "SELECT Id FROM Our_View WHERE FirstName=? AND LastName=?", new Object[]{person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName()}, int.class);
```

But, for Updatable and Insertable views in Mysql, refer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html)